# Rails 3 is out and now there is no documentation online for 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation

I thought I would start a wiki for links to old rails documentation since "Rails 3 is greatest thing since sliced bread" :). Rails 3 IS awesome, but I'm not moving to it yet. I can't find docs for 2.3.5 or 2.3.8 anywhere. The closest I can find to what I need is this:

http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html

+1 to anyone who can find some good 2.3.x documentation!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/

ok? :)

Answer (score 1):

[railsapi.com](http://www.railsapi.com/) is a great site:

Direct link to 2.3.8:

http://www.railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/

Answer (score 0):

[APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails) makes it very easy to see past versions of Ruby and Rails documentation (as well as see which versions changed documentation and comment on documentation).